# Databinding to a single item in a collection

Tags: knockout.js

If I have an observable array in my view model I can access individual items in that array using the item's position within my script:

```
alert(this.travellers()[0].Age);
```

However, I cant seem to databind to the item/property using similar syntax in my view:

```html
<label data-bind="text: travellers()[0].Age" />
```

Again, I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, it just depends on where you are doing the binding to tell whether `travellers` is available at that level.

If you are inside of a template, then you would want to consider passing this value in via `templateOptions` or if your viewModel has global scope you could reference it like `text: yourViewModel.travellers()[0].Age`.

Sample with each option: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/brAtZ/